# How to format a column in the PnP Search Results Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts

I'm trying to get a column in my PnP Search Results web part on a SharePoint site to be blue or grey for the background color, depending on the content in the column. The Visit Page column should be grey if the page is coming soon or blue if the page is available, so it should look like this:

[what column should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aBV5.png)

For the Visit Page column, this is what I have:

`

{{#if slot item @root.slots.PreviewUrl.length <= 53}}

<a href="{{slot item @root.slots.PreviewUrl}}" target="_blank" style = "

```
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

cursor:pointer;

border:none;

color:white;

font-weight:550;

background-color:#A4A4A4;

text-decoration:none;

font-size:14px;

text-align:center;

display: flex;

justify-content: center;

">

           {{slot item @root.slots.VisitPage}}
```

```
{{else}}
```

<a href="{{slot item @root.slots.PreviewUrl}}" target="_blank" style = "

```
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

cursor:pointer;

border:none;

color:white;

font-weight:550;

background-color:#0078d4;

text-decoration:none;

font-size:14px;

text-align:center;

display: flex;

justify-content: center;

">

           {{slot item @root.slots.VisitPage}}
```

```
{{/if}}`
```

When I try the code above I get a parse error:
[parse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2nND.png)

I've also tried using #ifeq but I get a different error instead.